dotnet test --filter not filtering for Nunit test in Azure devops
Nunit test is not filtering the test fixtures, executed all test cases irrespective of the filter.
dotnet test myproject --filter TestCategory="Smoke" 

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet test
    continueOnError: True
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: '**/myproject.csproj'
      arguments: --filter TestCategory="SmokeTest"

Tried the above command in Azure devops pipeline dotnet task and also from package manager console in visual studio. It just simply didn't work no error message

Your syntax looks correct, but you might be missing details in your question that would allow others to answer it.  Can you post what your pipeline looks like and what the logs are showing?

@bryanbcook added the pipeline task for your reference

I'm more concerned about "It just simply didn't work no error message". There should be output from the pipeline task.

Got it fixed, Actually I have added the 'Category' in base test as well. After removing that it is working.

Using --filter TestCategory=... in dotnet, it works fine on my side. This is my test.
using NUnit.Framework;
using Prime.Services;

namespace Prime.UnitTests.Services
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class PrimeService_IsPrimeShould
    {
        private PrimeService _primeService;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _primeService = new PrimeService();
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("LessThan2")]
        [TestCase(-1)]
        [TestCase(0)]
        [TestCase(1)]
        public void IsPrime_ValuesLessThan2_ReturnFalse(int value)
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(_primeService.IsPrime(value), $"{value} should not be prime");
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("PrimesLessThan10")]
        [TestCase(2)]
        [TestCase(3)]
        [TestCase(5)]
        [TestCase(7)]
        public void IsPrime_PrimesLessThan10_ReturnTrue(int value)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(_primeService.IsPrime(value), $"{value} should be prime");
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("NonPrimesLessThan10")]
        [TestCase(4)]
        [TestCase(6)]
        [TestCase(8)]
        [TestCase(9)]
        public void IsPrime_NonPrimesLessThan10_ReturnFalse(int value)
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(_primeService.IsPrime(value), $"{value} should not be prime");
        }
    }
}

Use --filter TestCategory=... in dotnet.
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/PrimeService.Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage" --filter TestCategory=PrimesLessThan10'

Then I can see only test cases with "PrimesLessThan10" category are executed.


Update: Set Category attribute at TestFixture level.
Sample test file:
using NUnit.Framework;
using Prime.Services;

namespace Prime.UnitTests.Services
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("Test1")]
    public class PrimeService_IsPrimeShouldTest1
    {
        private PrimeService _primeService;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _primeService = new PrimeService();
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(-1)]
        [TestCase(0)]
        [TestCase(1)]
        public void IsPrime_ValuesLessThan2_ReturnFalseTest1(int value)
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(_primeService.IsPrime(value), $"{value} should not be prime");
        }

    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Category("Test2")]
    public class PrimeService_IsPrimeShouldTest2
    {
        private PrimeService _primeService;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _primeService = new PrimeService();
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(-1)]
        [TestCase(0)]
        [TestCase(1)]
        public void IsPrime_ValuesLessThan2_ReturnFalseTest2(int value)
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(_primeService.IsPrime(value), $"{value} should not be prime");
        }

    }

}

Run use arguments: '--filter TestCategory=Test2' in DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. Only test cases in PrimeService_IsPrimeShouldTest2 are executed.


Update:
Ensure you use Category correctly, see Category for the detailed info.
Solution: Removing 'Category' from base test resolve the issue.

Yes, I had same structure. But I did added the 'Category' attribute to 'TestFixture' not at 'Test' level. That is my requirement.

I have just tested setting Category attribute at TestFixture level. It works fine. According to your description, you have the same issue in VS. I am guessing it's related to your project itself. Please check whether you set Category correctly. Update my test with you above for your reference.

Got it fixed, Actually I have added the 'Category' in base test as well. After removing that it is working like a charm.

@Devanathan M, it's great to know the issue resolved. To help others who may have the same issue, I updated your root cause in my answer above to make it clearer.
